# Converting an Excel Formula to a Mathematical Function

Tags: functions

I'm normally to be found on the DBA.SE site where I post and answer questions related to database problems.

Some questions related to the amount of memory to reserve for a SQL Server instance can be answered with a formula that was developed by Jonathan Kehayias as:

> ...to reserve 1 GB of RAM for the OS, 1 GB for each 4 GB of RAM installed from 4–16 GB, and then 1 GB for every 8 GB RAM installed above 16 GB RAM...

<sup>***Reference:*** [How much memory does my SQL Server actually need?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/)</sup>

In order to have a graph in Excel which I could print out and stick on the wall for anybody to read, I created a simple table with three columns.

$x$ = Amount of RAM in system
$y$ = Amount of RAM reserved for OS
$z$ = Amount or RAM reserved for SQL Server instance

The first column for the $x$ values contains a list of numbers from 4 to 2048 in increments of 4.

The second column for the $y$ values was initially calculated using the Excel formula:

$$y = IF(x<=16;1 + x/4;1 + 4 + (x-16)/8)$$

The third column for the $z$ values is calculated as:

$$z = x - y$$

I then improved my first formula for the $y$ values to use the following Excel formula:

$$y = 1 + MIN(x * 0.25;4) + (MAX((x-16);0) * 0.125)$$

The advantage is that I am no longer relying on an $IF$ to determine how values should be calculated.

## Questions

My mathematical skills have deteriorated over the years and this is why I would like to know...

- Is my formula a valid formula in simple mathematical terms?
- Can my formula for $y$ be written using only basic mathematical skills?

  - without the $MIN$ and $MAX$ functions of Excel

## Memory Distribution on a SQL Server instance

The logarithmic graph looks like this.

$x$ = HW Memory
$y$ = OS Memory
$z$ = SQL Server Memory

[image: Logarithmic graph of SQL Serer Memory allocation]

Comment: `min` and `max` are valid math functions, you can replace it by an absolute value.
$$y = \min\left(1 + \frac{x}{4},3 + \frac{x}{8}\right) = 2 + \frac{3x - |x-16|}{16}$$

Comment: Thanks for the end formula. Could you post that as an answer for me and explain the steps required to simplify my formula into yours? Or is the too basic for this site? I know you can multiply and divide on both sides of a formula, but how do you $$-min$$ on both sides of a formula?